# Expression Blend WPF Application Can't Change between Defined States

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, expression-blend

In my WPF application, which I have done in `Expression Blend`, I have defined some States (like 'SunAnimation', 'SnowAnimation' etc.). Now if I switch between these States while the program is not running (in the Design Mode), everything works fine. But when I run the program and I try to change the States using the `VisualStateManager.GoToState(...)` it does not work at all.

The code I have in the file behind is

```
    void comboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, Dynamic_State.Text.ToString(), true);
    }
```

Dynamic_State is a TextBlock where the name of the state is automatically loaded (through DataBinding) depending on what is being selected in the ComboBox.

In the WPF File I have several storyboard defined like the following:

```html
<Storyboard x:Key="SunAnimation" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
   <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[2].(RotateTransform.Angle)" Storyboard.TargetName="Rays">
    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:4" Value="36"/>
   </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
   <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.OpacityMask).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[2].(GradientStop.Offset)" Storyboard.TargetName="ellipse">
    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0.95"/>
    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2" Value="0.221"/>
    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:4" Value="0.95"/>
   </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
  </Storyboard>
```

I also have some `ControlStoryboardAction` stuff defined (according to a tutorial, but I am not really sure if that is somehow useful or necessary at all....) as well as a `VisualStateGroups` which looks like the following:

```html
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
   <i:EventTrigger>
    <ei:ControlStoryboardAction Storyboard="{StaticResource SunAnimation}"/>
    <ei:ControlStoryboardAction Storyboard="{StaticResource RainAnimation}"/>
    <ei:ControlStoryboardAction Storyboard="{StaticResource CloudAnimation}"/>
    <ei:ControlStoryboardAction Storyboard="{StaticResource SnowAnimation}"/>
   </i:EventTrigger>
  </i:Interaction.Triggers>
  <VisualStateManager.CustomVisualStateManager>
   <ei:ExtendedVisualStateManager/>
  </VisualStateManager.CustomVisualStateManager>
  <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
   <VisualStateGroup x:Name="WeatherStates">
    <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
     <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.5"/>
    </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
    <VisualState x:Name="None"/>
    <VisualState x:Name="Sunny">
     <Storyboard>
      <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="Sun">
       <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
      </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
     </Storyboard>
    </VisualState>
    <VisualState x:Name="Rainy">
     <Storyboard>
      <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="Rain">
       <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
      </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
      <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="Sun">
       <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
      </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
      <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[0].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="WeatherGrid">
       <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#FF00427A"/>
      </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
      <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="WeatherGrid">
       <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#FF637685"/>
      </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
     </Storyboard>
    </VisualState>
    <VisualState x:Name="Cloudy">
     <Storyboard>
      <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="clouds">
       <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
      </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
     </Storyboard>
    </VisualState>
    <VisualState x:Name="Snowy">
     <Storyboard>
      <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="snowflakes">
       <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
      </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
      <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[0].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="path6">
       <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#FF9EA19F"/>
      </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
      <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[0].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="path7">
       <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#FF9EA19F"/>
      </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
      <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[0].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="path8">
       <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#FF9EA19F"/>
      </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
      <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[0].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="path9">
       <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#FF9EA19F"/>
      </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
      <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="path6">
       <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="White"/>
      </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
      <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="path7">
       <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="White"/>
      </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
      <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="path8">
       <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="White"/>
      </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
      <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="path9">
       <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="White"/>
      </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
     </Storyboard>
    </VisualState>
   </VisualStateGroup>
  </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: have you tried adding the state in manually eg VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "Sunny" , true); if it still doesnt work its likely to be the location of the 'WeatherStates' VisualStateGroup

Comment: Yes I have tried this. Still does not work...What do you mean by 'the location of the 'WeatherStates' VisualStateGroup'?

Comment: Try move the VisualStatManager code just under your top level `Grid` or `Panel`. If that doesnt work strip out the Triggers and CustumVisualStateMananger test again and then re-add until problem is highlighted

Comment: Well I have tried this as well. But I actually am not sure at all where I have to move the VisualStateManager since I have multiple grids. 'https://www.dropbox.com/s/9tj7uirfnihkg1g/Weather.zip?dl=0 '. But maybe this is not the problem after all. Under the link you can see the whole code, maybe this can clarify what's really wrong. Will continue trying anything!

Comment: Another thing I thougt: Why can't I just use the different Storyboards, and depending on which Storyboard (e.g. SunAnimation, RainAnimation I want to see, I would set the opacity of the corresponding StoryBoard to 100%. But here the problem is that I haven't figured out how to change the opacity of the Storyboard to 0 or to 100 from the code behind. If I could do this, then I would not need the States at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had a look at your code again as couldn't see why the state change wasn't working.
Think this will help. 
Firstly move your VisualStateManager and VisualStates right under the `Grid` `LayoutRoot` eg

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Black" Width="960" Height="540" DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource SampleWeatherData}}">
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
         <VisualStateGroup x:Name="WeatherStates">
            //all your other VisualStates
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>...
```

then change your code slightly to

```
void comboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    VisualStateManager.GoToElementState(LayoutRoot, "Sunny", true);
}
```

**EDIT** Not sure you have to do the first stage of this answer. test it and let me know

I think this should work. GL

Comment: Works like a charm now. As you said it was important to specify from which FrameworkElement (here `LayoutRoot`) one is calling the change state function. Also calling the function `GoToElementState` instead of `GoToState` is necessary. 
Thank you very much, much appreciate it!!!!!

Comment: thats great news. Could you mark it as the correct answer :)

Comment: Yes I'll do. Sorry that I did not respond until now!!!
So I think I marked it now (is this what you meant?) :-)
Can I also somehow rate you (your profile)?